# Why do I get error with complicated condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to retrieve all the comments that contains particular keyword.
But it also has to be active users comments.
Active user can be retrieved by `user_ids = User.all`
So I coded like this but I get the error. How can I solve this?

```
user_ids = User.all
commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s
@comments = Comment.where('user_id=? AND commentable_type=? AND body like ?', user_ids, commentable, "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

**Error Message**

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your user_ids is an array. use IN instead of = in your query.

```
@comments = Comment.where('user_id IN (?) AND commentable_type=? AND body like ?', user_ids.map(&:id), commentable, "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: Thanks! now it returns this error though `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds......`

Answer (score 0):

```
user_ids = User.pluck(:id)
commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s
@comments = Comment.where('user_id IN (?) AND commentable_type = ? AND body like ?', user_ids, commentable, "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

The above query will give you the desired result you want

Comment: There's reason why I'm doing. Because Some users are already deleted and their posted comments are still alive. In this action. I want to exclude all the comments posted by deleted user.

Comment: SO, you should query it like `user_ids = User.pluck(:id)`. This will be faster than `User.all` since it fires the query as `Select * from users` and any query with * is always slow as comapred to query that fetches only specific columns

Comment: But this time, I will vote up joreal's answer since he answered first, and it was correct answer, too. Thanks anyway!!